# Kubernetes job debug command

Tags: kubernetes

I wrote a job and I always get init error. I have noticed that if I remove the related `command` all goes fine and I do not get any init error.
My question is: how can I debug commands that need to run in the job? I use pod describe but all I can see is an exit status code 2.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: database-import
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: download-dump
          image: google/cloud-sdk:alpine
           command: #####            ERROR HERE!!!
             - bash
             - -c
             - "gsutil cp gs://webshop-254812-sbg-data-input/pg/spryker-stg.gz /data/spryker-stage.gz"
      volumeMounts:
        - name: application-default-credentials
          mountPath: "/secrets/"
          readOnly: true
        - name: data
          mountPath: "/data/"
      env:
        - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
          value: /secrets/application_default_credentials.json
  containers:
    - name: database-import
      image: postgres:9.6-alpine
      command:
        - bash
        - -c
        - "gunzip -c /data/spryker-stage.gz |  psql -h postgres -Uusername -W spy_ch "
      env:
        - name: PGPASSWORD
          value: password
      volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: "/data/"
  volumes:
    - name: application-default-credentials
      secret:
        secretName: application-default-credentials
    - name: data
      emptyDir: {}
  restartPolicy: Never
backoffLimit: 4
```

And this is the job describe:

```
Name:           database-import
Namespace:      sbg
Selector:       controller-uid=a70d74a2-f596-11e9-a7fe-025000000001
Labels:         app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=tilt
Annotations:    <none>
Parallelism:    1
Completions:    1
Start Time:     Wed, 23 Oct 2019 15:11:40 +0200
Pods Statuses:  1 Running / 0 Succeeded / 3 Failed
Pod Template:
Labels:  app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=tilt
       controller-uid=a70d74a2-f596-11e9-a7fe-025000000001
       job-name=database-import
Init Containers:
 download-dump:
 Image:      google/cloud-sdk:alpine
Port:       <none>
Host Port:  <none>
Command:
  /bin/bash
  -c
  gsutil cp gs://webshop-254812-sbg-data-input/pg/spryker-stg.gz /data/spryker-stage.gz
Environment:
  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS:  /secrets/application_default_credentials.json
Mounts:
  /data/ from data (rw)
  /secrets/ from application-default-credentials (ro)
Containers:
 database-import:
 Image:      postgres:9.6-alpine
 Port:       <none>
 Host Port:  <none>
 Command:
   /bin/bash
   -c
   gunzip -c /data/spryker-stage.gz |  psql -h postgres -Uusername -W 
spy_ch 
Environment:
  PGPASSWORD:  password
Mounts:
  /data/ from data (rw)
Volumes:
 application-default-credentials:
Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
SecretName:  application-default-credentials-464thb4k85
Optional:    false
data:
 Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
 Medium:     
 SizeLimit:  <unset>
 Events:
 Type    Reason            Age   From            Message
  ----    ------            ----  ----            -------
 Normal  SuccessfulCreate  2m5s  job-controller  Created pod: database-import-9tsjw
 Normal  SuccessfulCreate  119s  job-controller  Created pod: database-import-g68ld
 Normal  SuccessfulCreate  109s  job-controller  Created pod: database-import-8cx6v
 Normal  SuccessfulCreate  69s   job-controller  Created pod: database-import-tnjnh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to see the log of an init container ran in a job is:

```
kubectl logs -f <pod name>  -c <initContainer name>
```

Answer (score 0):

You check the logs using

```
Kubectl logs <Pod name>
```

Pod name is completed job or running job.

In logs you can more idea about error and easily you can debug the job on running on Kubernetes.

If you are using the Kubernetes Cluster on GKE and enabled the stackdriver monitoring then you can use it also for debugging.

Comment: All I get from the log is : Error from server (BadRequest): container "database-import" in pod "database-import-d5dbt" is waiting to start: PodInitializing

Comment: In your pod spec there init container that is issue i think generating issue

Answer (score 0):

> [Init:Error](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-init-containers/#understanding-pod-status) -> Init Container has failed to execute.

That is because there are some errors in the initContainers command section

[There](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-initialization/) You can read how the yaml should be prepared.

I have fixed your yaml file.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: database-import
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: database-import
        image: postgres:9.6-alpine
        command:
          - bash
          - "-c"
          - "gunzip -c /data/spryker-stage.gz |  psql -h postgres -Uusername -W spy_ch "
        env:
          - name: PGPASSWORD
            value: password
        volumeMounts:
          - name: data
            mountPath: "/data/"
      initContainers:
      - name: download-dump
        image: google/cloud-sdk:alpine
        command:
          - /bin/bash
          - "-c"
          - "gsutil cp gs://webshop-254812-sbg-data-input/pg/spryker-stg.gz /data/spryker-stage.gz"
        env:
          - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
            value: /secrets/application_default_credentials.json
        volumeMounts:
          - name: application-default-credentials
            mountPath: "/secrets/"
            readOnly: true
          - name: data
            mountPath: "/data/"
      volumes:
      - name: application-default-credentials
        secret:
          secretName: application-default-credentials
      - name: data
        emptyDir: {}
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

Result after `kubectl apply -f job.yaml`

```
job.batch/database-import created
```

Let me know if it works now.

EDIT

Use `kubectl describe job <name of your job>` and add results,we will see why it is not working then.

Comment: Thanks but still initerror. Is there a way to see the command job logs?

Comment: please try `gsutil ls -r gs://webshop-254812-sbg-data-input/**  && sleep 300'` within your init container and verify if there is problem with accessing your bucket

Comment: How I do it in initconainer?

Comment: Added job description

Comment: Hey @StefanoMaglione did you solve your problem? You can use the above command in the initContainer command section, instead of this `"gsutil cp gs://webshop-254812-sbg-data-input/pg/spryker-stg.gz /data/spryker-stage.gz"`,then check initContainer logs and see if it works.